Ubuntu 22.04 kernel 5.15.0 boots to zero screen brightness on Lenovo P51
I have a Lenovo P51 upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS;
It now boots to a black screen (subtle behavior, read on).
The graphics hardware available are Intel Corporation HD Graphics P630 and NVIDIA Corporation GM206GLM, and the kernels available are 5.15.0-43-generic and 5.15.0-43-generic.
Behavior:

Kernel 5.15.0-43-generic: Briefly boots to an empty desktop with cursor before halting at a solid black screen (not a desktop session with zero screen brightness).
Kernel 5.15.0-41-generic: Boots briefly to a normal tty1 login prompt, then to a gray screen with a visible mouse cursor, then to a fully working normal desktop with the backlight brightness at 0. I can dimly see that expected windows are present and system is responsive. Keyboard brightness controls do nothing.
Kernel 5.15.0-41-generic (recovery mode): Boots normally—but there is no keyboard or software control of screen brightness.

If relevant, I'm booting into a mate-session (Ubuntu Mate).
This behavior emerged yesterday after a reboot following apt-get upgrade; Prior to this, the system had been running continuously for 2–3 weeks and seemed OK with the exception of these warning signs:

I lost keyboard control of screen brightness.
In the months prior, the system would never resume after closing the laptop lid (jet black screen, not the working screen with brightness zero described for 5.15.0-41 above).

As you might imagine, I've spent the usual day's labor combing through other forum posts and following debug steps for vaguely similar issues, but haven't been able to solve it. Any ideas?

The system was in an inconsistent state following the 22.04 upgrade due to kept back nvidia packages. As a result, sudo apt upgrade was not pulling in the bug fixes.
Running sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade pulled in graphics driver updates as well as kernel 5.15.0-107-generic.

On the first reboot, the behavior was similar to 5.15.0-41-generic: It booted to a desktop session with zero brightness and non-working keyboard brightness controls. However, ctl+alt+f1 brought in a working tty1 terminal login session (medium brightness), which could then be switched over to a desktop session with nonzero brightness. (May have just needed some time).

On the second reboot, it booted to a zero-brightness desktop session, but with working keyboard brightness controls.

On the third reboot, it booted to a normal brightness desktop session, albeit with more toggling on/off of the graphics backlight during boot than previous Ubuntu releases.

Suspend now "works" for the first time in months (with glitches).


